# Get table name from database field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server Management Studio 17.0.  I have a table which controls separate tables for different files, something like:

```
 filename | tablename
 ---------+----------
 file1    | table1
 file2    | table2
```

I need to `select from tablename`, but not hardcoded. Filename comes from web, and I can fist get the tablename, like

```
select tablename 
from filetables 
where filename = "file1"
```

and use it to view the file table:

```
select * 
from (table1)
```

Is there any way to do it in SQL? Something like

```
Select * 
from 
    (select tablename 
     from filetables 
     where filename = "file1")
```

Comment: You can only do this through [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) like in a stored procedure. And, while not always true, this is usually symptomatic of poor database design. A table of tables, table of fields (or a database in a database) is a common anti-pattern in DB design. So there may be lots of pain down this path.

Comment: Unfortunately, that it what left from previous team. And yes, thats painful for us now to fix huge number of problems - I feel like it would be easier to write the app from scratch)

Answer (score 3):

You can't select from a table that can only be determined at run time and/or depending on some parameter. Your only option is to use a Dynamic SQL in this case but make sure you don't expose yourself to SQL-Injection attacks.

[Here's a link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulga/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection/) on how to safely create Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score -1):

```
   DECLARE @v_sql        NVARCHAR(MAX),
           @v_table_name NVARCHAR(MAX),
           @v_file_name  NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @v_file_name  = 'file1' -- Populated from web proc

    SELECT @v_table_name = tablename
      FROM filetables
     WHERE filename = REPLACE(@v_file_name, '''', '') 

    SELECT @v_sql =

   'SELECT *
      FROM ' + @v_table_name + '
     WHERE filename = ''' + @v_file_name + ''''

    SELECT @v_sql -- Debug code to show you the statement prior to running

    EXEC sp_executesql @v_sql
```

You will need to utilize dynamic SQL like other users here have answered. Give this a shot in your environment and see how it goes.

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL-Injection attacks despite the fact that you are using sp_executesql.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I assumed the asker would read the link you provided and I just gave them a bare bones executable for their needs. You are correct that this needs sanitizing.

Comment: I have edited the code to sanitize the file name provided by the web proc.

Comment: that's not going to work either. You need to parametrize the statement itself rather than doing string concatenation and string replacement. My link has an example on how to do it properly.